# How can I programmatically add members to a group?

Tags: 8, users, group

I am trying add members to a group programmatically using Groups module in Drupal 8, and I am doing the following to achieve this:

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase;
$roles = array('test_role');
$values = ['group_roles' => $roles, 'gid' => 1];
$account = $this->createUser();
$group = \Drupal\group\Entity\Group::load(1);
$group->addMember($account, $values);
```

So, users are already present in the site. I want to add only those users to a group who have successfully paid for it. Hence, I am trying to write a custom solution that I add a user to an already existing group on the site. I came across this addMember($account, $values) function in the group module, however am still not sure on what values its arguments ($account and $values) take. Above piece of code does not add users to my group. Can someone please suggest what wrong I am doing here?

Comment: Please explain what is not working, that helps us answer you. From the looks, you are not saving the created user. Try to add ->save(); after createUser()

Comment: Hi @Neograph734, Thanks for your response. I have edited my question above. I hope I have made it a little more clear. adding ->save() after createUser() doesn't seem to solve this. Can you please suggest something more on this? Thank you very much.

Comment: If users already exist, why do you create a user? (`$account = $this->createUser();`) Can't you load an existing user instead: `$account = \Drupal\group\Entity\User::load(1);`?

Comment: Yes that is right actually. I am now loading an existing user and passing that as an argument in addMember function. However still it does not add the user to the group.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't see anything else... What if you remove the gid from $values? You should not have to set that anyway. Maybe someone else has a good insight.

Comment: Sure, I am setting gid because otherwise then how should I make sure to add a user to group 1 and not group 2. Thank you very much for looking into this.

Comment: Because you already loaded group 1 and are calling the function for that group ;) See line 102: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/group/tree/src/Entity/GroupInterface.php

Comment: Yes great! So, I am able to add members to a group now. I modified the code to this:

    $account = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(7);
    $group = \Drupal\group\Entity\Group::load(1);
    $group->addMember($account);
    $group->save();

Comment: Saving the group crossed my mind, but I didn't think it would help... Can you add the answer yourself?

Answer (score 5):

So, modifying the code a little bit and saving the group after adding member to it worked for me. Pasting the updated code below:

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase;
$account = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
$group = \Drupal\group\Entity\Group::load($group_id);
$group->addMember($account);
$group->save();
```

Answer (score 3):

Without 'gid' code below works for me:

```
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
$group = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('group')->load(127);
$group->addMember($user, ['group_roles' => ['podrazdelenie-admin']]);
$group->save();
```